# Write a telephone number in a website for the Iphone

Tags: iphone, xhtml

How I can write a phone number in the xhtml file and when the user clicks (on the number) the iphone call automatically (to that number)?

Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks @Moshe, like this is perfect: <a href="tel:2128675309">link-text 2128675309</a> good answer at the bottom :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<a href="tel:2128675309">call Jenny</a>
```

Comment: What happens on non-iphone devices?

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that the format -from my own testing just now- is `<a href="tel:2128675309">link-text 2128675309</a>`.

Comment: @Moshe, I can't say for sure, but it seems to be an official RFC (http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3966.txt), so they should be able to work with it.